# How To extend the user privileges in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am a new bee. I dont know how to extend the user privileges in Wordpress.Tried Hard To find the solution... But all my efforts are in vain.I just wanna know how to extend the user privileges? I wanna give particular plugin(Aqua Page Builder) access to all register users so that they can build thier own custom pages.Hope you guys help me out to get rid of this problem.Thanks In Advance

Comment: [Could be useful](http://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if i am right in understanding your question, you have a plugin installed and that plugin has a section in Admin. What you want is to offer access to registered users for that Section ?

There are 2 solutions for this.

1 - you can edit the function for registered user and write little code there for showing users that section as well. it's simple - you only need little php and wordpress API knowledge.

2 - Second solution is immediate and easy. Install some plugin that can do this for you. I Googled for you and found a plugin **ADMINIZE** , see more in plugin details and screenshots here: http://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/

Comment: One more thing, don't forget to mark answer as ACCEPTED and VOTE for my answer please. Click "Arrow UP" icon for voting & TICK icon for selecting answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks a lot shumail..Really pleased with your effort. Bit near to destination.. Since i am in dead end i have to prefer second option.That too not successful.. Can you elaborate 1st option please... i.e where to make changes ...as mentioned earlier i am a new bee can't get you immediately